# Did the U.S. take any measure to prevent China from benefiting from friendshoring?

Tags: united-states, china, economy

> China is moving to deepen trade and investment links with nations the
> US has prioritized for friend-shoring, a response that may keep—or
> even enhance—Beijing’s primacy in global commerce.
>
> President Xi Jinping’s visit this week to Vietnam, a rare 2024 trip
> outside his country, showcased how he isn’t standing idly by while
> Washington attempts to diminish China’s role in supply chains that end
> in American consumption. The trip came just three months after
> President Joe Biden’s own visit, which yielded agreements on
> everything from semiconductors to security ties...
>
> When Western capitals realize their friend-shoring project is being
> undermined, the risk is a new wave of protectionist backlash.

https://www.bloomberg.com/news/newsletters/2023-12-16/china-isn-t-taking-friend-shoring-lying-down

Did the U.S. take any measure to prevent China from benefiting from friendshoring? Friendshoring was intended to diminish reliance with China and help friends instead of helping China, which the U.S. sees as a threat, but it seems like China is just integrating itself tighter to the global economy by making itself indispensable to the frienshored nations. Did the U.S. government take any action to prevent that from happening?

Comment: So, "friendshoring" is just offshoring, but to countries with good relations? Which offshoring usually is anyway, because it is easier to employ and trade with people in countries that have better relations with one's own government.